# How to get the Data Type of a Specific Column in H2 Database

Tags: h2

I can get all column data by using the following query.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name;
```

I want to get data of "column_name" only.
i tried the following query as well. but still didnt work.

```
SELECT data_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name';
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```sql
select type_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name='Table_name' and column_name='columnName';
```

Answer (score 2):

The right query for the latest H2 is:

```
show columns from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a join with table **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TYPE_INFO** , the correct query is:

```sql
SELECT i.type_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TYPE_INFO i 
WHERE c.data_type=i.data_type AND c.table_name = 'table_name' AND c.column_name = 'column_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of uniqueness you also want to extend selection by schema name:

```sql
SELECT TYPE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE UPPER ( TABLE_SCHEMA ) = UPPER ( 'my_schemaname' ) 
AND UPPER ( TABLE_NAME ) = UPPER ( 'my_tablename' ) 
AND UPPER ( COLUMN_NAME ) = UPPER ( 'my_columnname' )
```